# Como filtrar dados por um padrão de texto no R

Tags: r, string, filter, dplyr

Tenho uma base de dados com dados de cidades e estados brasileiros, gostaria de filtrar somente os estados, todos seguem um padrão de ter um "br_states_" antes do nome do estado. Tentei utilizar o pacote `string` e a função `filter` do pacote `dplyr`, porém sem sucesso.

Código que estou utilizando:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dados <- read_csv('http://tiny.cc/idb-traffic-daily') %>%
  filter(country_name == "Brazil") %>%
  str_detect(pattern = "br_states_")
```

Comment: O que faltou no seu código foram duas coisas.1) o `str_detect` deve estar dentro do `filter`. 2) Você precisa informar para o `str_detect` onde ele deve buscar o padrão, ou seja, fornecer o primeiro argumento. Algo assim: `filter(..., str_detect(region_slug, "br_states_"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a função `grep`. Ela permite que se procure trechos de strings. Ao combiná-la com a função `filter` do pacote `dplyr`, é possível manter apenas as linhas da coluna `region_slug` que possuam `br_states`:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

dados <- read_csv('http://tiny.cc/idb-traffic-daily') %>%
  filter(grepl("br_states", region_slug))
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!